# NIntegrate stuck without any warning

Tags: numerical-integration, summation

My problem is to compute `W`:

```
β = 1/137;
i[k1_?NumericQ, k2_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
    SphericalBesselJ[l, k1*x] Exp[I*k*x] SphericalBesselJ[l, 
      k2*y] Exp[-β*y] x^(l + 1)/y^(l - 1), {x, 0, Infinity}, {y,
      x, Infinity}, PrecisionGoal -> 4] + 
   NIntegrate[
    SphericalBesselJ[l, k1*x] Exp[I*k*x] SphericalBesselJ[l, 
      k2*y] Exp[-β*y] y^(l + 2)/x^l, {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, 
     x}, PrecisionGoal -> 4];
W[k_, lmax_] := (1/137)^2 β^3/
   k 32/π Sum[
    NIntegrate[(
      Boole[Sqrt[k^2 - k2^2 - β^2] > 0] + 
       Boole[Sqrt[k^2 - k2^2 - β^2] < 0])/((2*l + 1) Sqrt[
       Abs[k^2 - k2^2 - β^2]])
       Abs[i[Sqrt[k^2 - k2^2 - β^2], k2, k, l]]^2 (k^2 - 
        k2^2 - β^2) k2^2, {k2, 0, Infinity}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 4], {l, 0, lmax}];

W[0.1, 0]
```

The integration lasts forever without any warnings. If the integration over $k2$ and the sum over $l$ are removed, then `W` calculates well with particular $k$'s and $l$ (AbsoluteTiming about 20 sec). What's wrong with this code?

Comment: 22 seconds for k2=0.01; k=0.1; l=1

Comment: (1) How do you set a value for `k2` in `W`? Doesn't it integrate over `0 <= k2 < Infinity`? (2) How long does the integral in `W` take for `l = 0`, `k = 0.1`?  For me I killed it after 400+ sec.

Comment: If it's the integral `i[]` that takes 22 sec., then `W[]` is integrating that integral many times, maybe hundreds of times or more.  That suggests it might take a few hours.

Comment: It does, but to check the problem i tried particular k2 and k.

Comment: I waited a night without result, so i'm not sure if this code is ok.

Comment: `i[Sqrt[0.1^2 - 0.01^2 - \[Beta]^2], 0.01, 0.1, 0]` took my computer 66 sec.  I think you might have a difficult integral to evaluate.  I was going to suggest that instead of `Sum`, which is primarily a symbolic solver, you might try `Total@Table[...]` instead, but that won't speed up the individual integrals. -- I see nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: In definition of W i putted k1 as a function of k2 inside i, however k1 is NumercQ variable. Is it ok?

Comment: `NIntegrate` support multidimensional integration.

Comment: You know `Sqrt[u]` is never negative, so `Boole[Sqrt[k^2 - k2^2 - β^2] < 0]` might be a mistake. If not a mistake, you could replace it by zero.

Answer (score 2):

The following function is not defined at $k2^2>k^2-\beta^2$

```
Boole[Sqrt[k^2 - k2^2 - \[Beta]^2] > 0] + 
   Boole[Sqrt[k^2 - k2^2 - \[Beta]^2] < 0]
```

assuming that

```
\[Beta] = 1/137; 
f[k_, k2_] := 
 Boole[Sqrt[k^2 - k2^2 - \[Beta]^2] > 0] + 
  Boole[Sqrt[k^2 - k2^2 - \[Beta]^2] < 0]
Table[{k2, f[.1, k2]}, {k2, 0, .1, .01}]
```

We have out

```
    {{0., 1}, {0.01, 1}, {0.02, 1}, {0.03, 1}, {0.04, 1}, {0.05, 
  1}, {0.06, 1}, {0.07, 1}, {0.08, 1}, {0.09, 1}, {0.1, 
  Boole[0. + 0.00729927 I > 0] + Boole[0. + 0.00729927 I < 0]}}
```

And two warnings

```
Greater::nord: Invalid comparison with 0. +0.00729927 I attempted.

Less::nord: Invalid comparison with 0. +0.00729927 I attempted.
```

Comment: `NIntegrate` does not complain about nonnumeric integrand values, which it usually does, so perhaps it is ignoring all values where the input to `Boole` is not `True`.  (It probably uses something like `PiecewiseExpand` to convert the `Boole` expressions, and apply singularity handlers to the piecewise domains. For example, `NIntegrate[Boole[Sqrt[1 - x^2] > 0], {x, 0, Infinity}]` and `NIntegrate[Boole[Sqrt[1 - x^2] < 0], {x, 0, Infinity}]`.)

Comment: Thank you! Nevertheless, I want to ask the author how he could define this function 'Boole[Sqrt[k^2 - k2^2 - \[Beta]^2] > 0] + 
   Boole[Sqrt[k^2 - k2^2 - \[Beta]^2] < 0]' for $k2^2>k^2-\beta^2$ ?

Comment: Good question. I left a related comment under the question. Here's more evidence that `Boole` is being given special handling by default: `NIntegrate[Boole[Sqrt[1 - x^2] > 0], {x, 0, Infinity}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]`, optionally wrapped with `Trace[..., _Message, TraceInternal -> True]`, to see the sort of errors one would expect from your analysis.

Comment: Good point. There was a mistake in kinematics of underlying process, so integration over k2 have physical limits. I also removed Boole(it was from symbolic integration with energy-conserving delta function). I got result after few hours without any warning so this question may be closed as it don't have Mathematica related sense.